# WPF Контрол поверх WindowsFormsHost

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms

Я понимаю, что на **EN Stackoverflow** есть подобные вопросы, но все же, мне не понятно, что не так с WindowsFormsHost?
Почему поверх него нельзя ставить WPF контрол?

Решения с AirSpace что-то там мне не помогает, т.к. постоянно делать скриншот того где рендерится видео не есть хорошо. Но мне просто необходимо отриcовать контролл поверх него.

Answer (score 0):

Посмотри в сторону варианта с [ограничением порядка отрисовки](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/jaimer/2007/03/08/using-visualtreehelper-getdrawing-to-get-around-the-z-order-limitation-when-hosting-windows-forms-controls/).
Но правильнее всего будет избавиться от WindowsFormsHost и переписать нужный контрол под WPF.

Comment: Так бы и сделал, но у контролов WPF нет Handle :)

Comment: @Birdy А хэндла окна через `HwndSource` или `WindowInteropHelper` тебе недостаточно? Опять же - зачем? Если используется для рисования, то есть родной `D3DImage`, которому через `SetBackBuffer` также можно спустить нативный буфер.

Comment: Хм, а за это спасибо, попозже рассмотрю данный класс.